# JfreeChart fix the Pie Chart Radius

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jFreeChart and ploting a pie chart with legend. 
radius of pie varies according to legend ,so i want to fix the size of pie chart(Plot area)

```
RingPlot plot = new RingPlot(dataset);
StringBuffer chartFileName = new StringBuffer(Integer.toString(generatedCharts)).append(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())).append(".png");

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), new Color(20, 20, 20), new Point(400, 200), Color.DARK_GRAY));

TextTitle t = chart.getTitle();
t.setHorizontalAlignment(org.jfree.ui.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
t.setPaint(new Color(240, 240, 240));
t.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 26));

plot.setBackgroundPaint(null);
plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
plot.setSectionDepth(0.35);
plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
plot.setSimpleLabels(true);
plot.setShadowPaint(null);
plot.setOuterSeparatorExtension(0);
plot.setInnerSeparatorExtension(0);
plot.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{1}",new DecimalFormat("#,##0"), new DecimalFormat("0.000%")));
plot.setLabelBackgroundPaint(null);
plot.setLabelOutlinePaint(null);

Font font=new Font("",0,16);
plot.setLabelFont(font);

chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
chart.getLegend().setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM); 
chart.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);
chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(4, 8, 2, 2));
```

Comment: When you open a SO account, did you bother to read the rules. How in the hell is anyone supposed to help you if there is no code associated with your question.  Also, did you bother to check [JFreeChart Forums](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=3&sid=3c0597200f771c6e2829bed40173fb4c) for answers?  They have plenty of these questions answered there as well.

Comment: Explain your problem better.  What do you mean by "i want to fix the size of pie chart(Plot area)"?  What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Also, `dataset` and `generatedCharts` are not properly defined.  Add complete code.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to add your code to an `ApplicationFrame` and I got this:

[image]

I do have a few observations:

1. Use the factory instead of invoking constructors directly. For example, your "pie chart" is actually a "ring chart." There are convenience methods to create different types or charts. For example: `JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createRingChart(...);`.
2. You can adjust the size of the pie using some or all of the following: `setInteriorGap()`, `setLabelGap()`, `setLabelLinkMargin()`, and/or `setMaximumLabelWidth()`.
3. If all you want is to change the radius of the chart, add the following code to yours:

   ```
   public static void setPieRadius(JFreeChart chart, double radius)
   {
       if (chart != null)
       {
           Plot plot = chart.getPlot();
           if (plot instanceof PiePlot)
           {
               PiePlot piePlot = (PiePlot) plot;
               double ig = 1.0 - radius;
               if (ig > PiePlot.MAX_INTERIOR_GAP)
               {
                   ig = PiePlot.MAX_INTERIOR_GAP;
               }
               piePlot.setInteriorGap(ig);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I am still not sure what is your question.  I suggest you get more `JFreeChart` pie chart examples and post a **SPECIFIC** problem description in JFreeChart forums (or here if you want).

Comment: I created my own dataset since you didn't provide one.

Comment: @Ammi if this answer satisfied your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: hey thanks for answer , my question was like while creating chart we have to specify chart width and height , and in dataset if i we have too long name for a particular value , then in that case legends are taking too much space for displaying name , in that size of chart is getting descrease , in short plot area is varing according to legends (key used for value)